# How can I fetch a list of data from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following a to-do list app tutorial from YouTube. I want to fetch a list of data from applications.
[image]

My code is like:

```
func fetchAllItems(completion: @escaping([TodoItem]) -> Void) {
  guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

  var allItems = [TodoItem]()

  ref.child("users").child(uid).child("applications").observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in

    fetchSingleItem(id: snapshot.key) { item in
      allItems.append(item)
      print(allItems)
      completion(allItems)
    }
  }
}
    
func fetchSingleItem(id: String, completion: @escaping(TodoItem) -> Void) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    ref.child("users").child(uid).child("applications").child(id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in

      guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
        return
      }
      let todoItem = TodoItem(keyID: id, dictionary: dictionary)
      print(todoItem)
      completion(todoItem)
    }
  }
}
```

The struct of TodoItem is like:

```
struct TodoItem {
  var title: String
  var isComplete: Bool
  init(keyID: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
    self.title = dictionary["title"] as? String ?? ""
    self.isComplete = dictionary["isComplete"] as? Bool ?? false
  }
}
```

But when I print allItems, only the first one shows in console. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your use of `if(value not nil)` and then `guard value` is confusing. The `guard` is doing the checking for you. No need for you to also do it.

Comment: Please can you link the YouTube tutorial. I feel like the tutorial is not correct. I'm not quite sure why you're observing events if you're trying to fetch data?

Comment: A couple of things, when posting questions about the Realtime database, please include the structure as text so we can use it in an answer; also be sure to include the full structure of a single node as often times paths are incorrect. Second thing is you're doing double the work you need to  - `.observe(.childAdded)` iterates over every child and returns it as a snapshot; there's no reason to read that exact same data again with `fetchSingleItem` as you already have it. Is there more to it or are you just trying to add each child node (application_1, applicaton_686 etc) to an array?

Comment: @Fogmeister This question is for the Realtime Database so the Firestore link on codable won't apply (it is a great article though!)

Comment: @Jay ah, my bad. Didn’t see that.